# Why does the Quartz job stop triggering and the state of the trigger changes from WAITING to ERROR?

Tags: java, spring, triggers, quartz-scheduler, jobs

**Issue Description:**

I have one Java service which is dynamically creating quartz job, trigger  and also saving these details into Quartz related tables.

If I forcibly stop tomcat server then the trigger state field of “Qrtz_triggers”  changed to ERROR.
And it never executes.

And if I change the state to WAITING then it start executing correctly.

**Quartz Configuration:**

```
<bean id="schedulerFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" lazy-init="false">
              <property name="schedulerName" value="IPASScheduler"/>
              <property name="autoStartup" value="true" />
              <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext" />
              <property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
              <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true" />
              <property name="dataSource">
                     <ref bean="dataSource" />
              </property>
              <property name="transactionManager">
                     <ref bean="transactionManager" />
              </property>
              <property name="jobFactory" ref="jobFactoryBean"/>
              <property name="quartzProperties">
                     <props>
                           <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold">6000000</prop>
                           <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate</prop>
                           <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered">true</prop>
                           <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval">20000</prop>
                           <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.class">org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX</prop>
                           <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName">IPASClusteredScheduler</prop>
                           <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId">AUTO</prop>
                           <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export">true</prop>
                           <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL">SELECT * FROM QRTZ_LOCKS WHERE LOCK_NAME = ?</prop>
                           <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">10</prop>
                           <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority">5</prop>
<!--                        <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.dontSetAutoCommitFalse">true</prop> -->
<!--                        <prop key="org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction">false</prop>  -->
<!--                        <prop key="org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties">false</prop>                        -->
                     </props>
              </property>                
       </bean>
```

**Java class for creation of Quartz Job and Quartz Trigger**

```
//creating Quartz job 
JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(ReportRunnerJob.class).withIdentity(jobName, "MY_REPORTING").build();



//Creating trigger            
CronTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity(triggerName, "MY_REPORTING").withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/10 * * * * ?")).withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed()).build();

                     Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler();
                     scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
                     scheduler.start();
                  //   Thread.sleep(1000L);
                  //   scheduler.shutdown(true);
```

**Job:**

```
public class ReportRunnerJob implements Job
{
       @Autowired
       private SessionFactory sessionFactoryReporting;
       @Autowired
       private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplateReporting;
       @Autowired
       private MailService mailService;*/
       @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println("Schedular job started");
}
}
```

Comment: and what is in the log?

Comment: Console doesn't show any erroneous log ...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to enable `DEBUG` log level for quartz.

I suspect, when you forcibly stop tomcat.
Your quartz trigger tries to load the `ReportRunnerJob` class, during those stopping moments, it fails and updates the Trigger status to "ERROR"